# How to get Windows screen orientation with Ruby and Win32API

Tags: ruby, winapi

I'm trying to get the Windows screen orientation to put an easter egg of sorts into a game that will occur when the display is upside down.

I know Fiddle exists, but that's not the question I've asked. If it can't be done in Win32API, just tell me that and I'll just ditch this minor feature.

Also, disclaimer, Ruby isn't the most familiar language to me, but I enjoy learning and overcoming challenges, so bring it on.

```
  class DisplayData < Struct.new(:dmFields)
    def initialize(dmFields=1); super end
  end

  def Win32API.orientation
    data = DisplayData.new()
    getDisplaySettings = Win32API.new('user32','EnumDisplaySettingsEx','%w(P I P)', 'l')
    getDisplaySettings.call("", -1, (data.object_id << 1))
    return data.dmFields
  end
```

I feel like I'm close, I just get the feeling I've missed something big or haven't understood something important properly.

Edit 1: The upside down screen to detect should be the one that the application is running in. If I've understood this correctly, parsing the nil value will return the screen settings for the screen that the application is running on.

Comment: Which screen, there can be more than one

Comment: My understanding is that as long as that first paramerer in the call to the Win32API is nil/null, Windows will return the settings for the screen that the application is running in. Unfortunaetly, you cant pass a nil value as a parameter in ruby when something else is required so I had to get creative. I think my solution for nil works. Someone with more experience may tell me otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ the code will like this:

```
DEVMODE devMode;
RtlSecureZeroMemory(&devMode, sizeof(DEVMODE));
devMode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
devMode.dmFields = DM_DISPLAYORIENTATION;

BOOL result = EnumDisplaySettingsEx(NULL, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &devMode, EDS_RAWMODE);
if (result)
{
    DWORD displayOrient = devMode.dmDisplayOrientation; // Get display device orientation
}
```

And

> To determine whether the display orientation is portrait or landscape
>   orientation, check the ratio of dmPelsWidth to dmPelsHeight.

Comment: RtlSecureZeroMemory() ??? Sounds geeky but why not write DEVMODE devMode{}; instead?